# Mixed Integer Optimisation Using cvxpy

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve an optimisation problem in python using CVXPY. Specifically, I am trying to optimise two available resources based on some data.

Below is a toy example of the problem I am having. I have some data **y** which can be thought of as a vector of daily unit demand and I have two resources which are available each day to meet this demand. *a* is a constant resource where the same amount will be available each day. *b* is essentially a daily quantity of buffer resource which can be used if needed.

There are three daily costs for the two resources, *a* has a standard cost, while *b* has a used cost and an unused cost.

There are two constraints, *a* must be positive and *b* can't be negative. I believe this should now be trivial as the optimal solution should be a=1 and b=0. Once this works I will add another constraint to limit the number of days taht are allowed to be under resourced

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# some random data
n_days = 5
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n_days)

# Two variables to be optimised - These are available resources, a is always used, b is used based on demand
a = cp.Variable(integer=True)
b = cp.Variable(integer=True)

# These are unit costs
r_a_used = 1
r_b_used = 1.5
r_b_unused = 0.2

a_used = a * n_days # The same amount of a will be used at every time point
b_unused = cp.sum(cp.maximum((b - cp.maximum((y - a), 0)), 0)) # calculate how much resource of b is used over all time points
b_used = (b * n_days) - b_unused # calculate how much resource of b is used at each time point

# Calculate the cost
cost = (a_used * r_a_used) + (b_used * r_b_used) + (b_unused * r_b_unused)

# Both a and b must be greater than equal to zero
constraints = [a >= 0, b >= -1]

# solve
objective = cp.Minimize(cost)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/toy_example.py", line 30, in <module>
    prob.solve()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 503, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 1072, in _solve
    data, solving_chain, inverse_data = self.get_problem_data(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 646, in get_problem_data
    solving_chain = self._construct_chain(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 898, in _construct_chain
    return construct_solving_chain(self, candidate_solvers, gp=gp,
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/solving_chain.py", line 217, in construct_solving_chain
    reductions = _reductions_for_problem_class(problem, candidates, gp, solver_opts)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/solving_chain.py", line 132, in _reductions_for_problem_class
    raise DCPError(
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
maximum(Promote(var2, (5,)) + -maximum([9. 5. 1. 5. 0.] + Promote(-var1, (5,)), 0.0), 0.0)
maximum(Promote(var2, (5,)) + -maximum([9. 5. 1. 5. 0.] + Promote(-var1, (5,)), 0.0), 0.0)
```

I  think this should be a convex optimisation problem, so I think it might be the formulation of the problem in CVXPY. Below are the visualisation trees of the atomic operations I am applying:

[image: To calculate a_used]

[image: To calculate b_unused]

[image: To calculate b_used]

If anyone could help then it would be greatly be appreciated.

(Edited based on Michal's comment below)

Comment: The function ``min(x,1)`` is not convex so you cannot minimize it or use it in an inequality such as ``min(x,1)+... <= bound``

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I realised this. However, when I reformulated the problem to only include maximum (which should be convex according to the docs) I am still getting the same error. I also removed the constraint currently with the minimum to simplify the problem initially (I think this should be trivial now). I have updated the question, and included the tree visualisations for each

Comment: ``max(0,a-max(b-y,0))`` which I see in your model is not a convex function. It cannot be convex because it takes two distinct constant values for large and small ``y``. max is convex so you cannot use ``-max``, which is concave, as an argument to max, which accepts convex arguments. The DCP rules are not just about which functions you  use but also their composition rules. Probably you need to make a mixed-integer model with implications if you really want to model this function, see for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#indicator-constraints